# Visual Composer Masonry Grid breaks site css

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode, visual-composer

I'm helping a friend with his wordpress site developed by someone else.
It uses Visual Composer and the css does not load in a page with a [vc_masonry_grid]. The content of the grid doesn't load either.
When I'm logged in the admin page, everything is fine and working. When logged out, the page breaks.

The page shortcode:

```
[vc_row][vc_column][vc_separator color="mulled_wine" style="dashed"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_masonry_grid post_type="post" max_items="9" element_width="3" gap="20" grid_id="vc_gid:1450646012663-59c888c1-a1a1-6" taxonomies="3" ][/vc_masonry_grid][/vc_row]
```

The console shows:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
eeaf7b97d3dcb25be243e07c875569c5.js:13*

*Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable your cache plugin or clear all cache using CTRL + F5